# Value Error : margin-left Parse Error margin-left

Tags: css, w3c

I keep getting a parse error when trying to validate this CSS in W3c but I don't understand what is wrong - help por favor:)
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnova.umuc.edu%2F~ct385d26%2Findex.html&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You’ve got

```
<span style="margin-left">
```

in line 29 of your `index.html`. You obviously need some value after that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is precisely at line 29 of the HTML (not the included CSS file). That line starts:

```
<span style="margin-left">
```

Which is obviously an erroneous `style` value; there is no colon or value.